# Write data into one file though several threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

How can I write data to a single file from multiple threads using ProcessPoolExecutor?
I faced with problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 234, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

my example [here](https://gist.github.com/AlexandrShinkevich87/26db1f1f106b9947ba212e1f5da29d65)

Answer (score 0):

- `ProcessPoolExecutor` uses separate processes, not threads.

  If you want threads, you need the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

  If you need separate processes, you can't share variables like that.
- Writing to the same file from multiple threads/processes is likely to be challenging. What are you trying to achieve? There may be an easier way to do it...

Comment: I get data from cassandra db asynchronously by id (I should handles 24 000 ids), after processing I should write all data in a single file.